# PC Chassis for MSI Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, case

I'm building my first Gaming computer, and I need some help deciding which case to get for my motherboard of choice. The motherboard I have chosen is the MSI Z270 Series Gaming Motherboard ([link](https://www.msi.com/asset/resize/image/global/product/product_9_20161213150334_584f9d46be2de.png62405b38c58fe0f07fcef2367d8a9ba1/1024.png)). The problem I face, is that I don't know which case would fit this motherboard nicely. I don't want to buy a case that doesn't allow me to fit my motherboard. I do know that the motherboard is ATX, so that means I need an ATX case, right?

The case that I am looking for should contain the following:

- Ability to mount a SSD and HDD
- Should be a full-on ATX Case (not MATX)
- Mount a Corsair PSU
- The case should have stand-offs already installed

I'm looking to spend around $100-$120 on a case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? i.e. What kind of case "form factor" do you want, such as full tower, cube etc... what's your budget for the case, drive bay requirements etc...

Comment: Ok. Will edit question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at the [NZXT Source 530](https://www.nzxt.com/products/source-530).

It fits all of your requirements:

- Can mount 1 SSD (2.5") and 1 HDD (3.5"), however it does have space for additional drives (3x 5.25", 6x 2.5" or 3.5")
- Full Tower ATX case (Fits ATX motherboards and is a Full Tower)
- Fits ATX PSUs
- Has standoff points and standoffs included in the box
- Within your budget. It can be found on [Amazon for $85](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FUC6S5O), [Newegg for $85](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811146114) and on [NZXT for $90](https://www.nzxt.com/products/source-530).

It also has a few nice features such as:

- Dust Filters
- Mounts for water cooling
- Modular drive cages
- Space for several fans (7-9 fans max, dependent on fan diameter)